# jQuery hide and show not properly (multiple times)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a problem with my project, on combination with jQuery/Coffeescript.

On my homepage I have a block with text, with an arrow underneath it.
Under there, there are buttons, and every time I have my mouse over one of those buttons, I want the text block + arrow to move.
I do this with the jQuery UI library, with the method `hide` and `show`.

In my CSS code I made several classes: `.position1`, `.position2` and `.position1`. Every time over hover with my mouse over one of the buttons, I want the text block to move to a specific position, so I change it's class (if someone has a better solution, I would gladly like to hear it).

Now the problem I'm having, is that sometimes the arrow hides and appears multiple times after each other (especially when I move my mouse very fast between the buttons)

A simple (partial) version of my jQuery is as follows:

```
var appear_arrow = function(to_position, show_delay) {
  removeClasses($('.arrow'));
  $('.arrow').addClass(to_class);
  $('.arrow').delay(show_delay).show('slide', 'slow');
};

var to_position1 = function() {
  $('.arrow').hide(0);
  $('.text_block').hide(appear);
  switchClass($('.text_block'));
  $('.text_block').show(appear);
  appear_arrow('position1', delay);
};

$('.button1').hover(
  function() {
    to_position1();
  },
  function() {}
);
```

My question, does anybody know why sometimes the arrow is appearing multiple times. Or does someone has a suggestion how to better do this?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery queues up all its animations on a given Element rather than resetting it first.

```
$("selector").stop(); // stops animations on matched elements and resets queue
```

A stop().fadeIn('slow') however will start from the opacity the element had when you called stop, which could be solved by for example hiding/showing it immediately, then doing a full fade at the new location - whatever looks best for you.

On a side note:

Seems you wrote wrapper functions for jQuery's removeClass and toggleClass methods.
removeClass() if called without arguments removes *all* classes, so you could possibly just use those if in a jQuery context anyway (assuming your methods have no extra functionality).

Seeing how often you call $('.arrow') you may want to cache your selectors, at least per iteration, then pass it to appear_arrow().

```
var $arrow = $('.arrow')
```

Comment: Dear @Flo, thanks you for your fast reply. Thing is, I would like it to be a bit smooth, then sudden transition is not a really good option for me. Also in my original code (written in coffee script) I am using those variable of course.

Comment: Then you could stop() the queue and add in a delta animation before adding the new positioning class and showing it again.

The new animation would calculate animation time depending on the state (i.e. opacity) of the elements (arrow currently at 0.2 opacity -> animation duration *= 0.2). But I might be overthinking things.